# Binary Search Tree Deletion Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

```
def __recursive_remove(self, value, root):

# the method returns the node with smallest value in a specific tree
def min_val_node(node):
  while node.left_child is not None:
    node = node.left_child
  return node

# Base case
if root is None:
  return root
# Search for the node to remove

# go left if the the node value is greater than input value
elif root.value > value:
  root.left_child = self.__recursive_remove(value, root.left_child)

#go right if the node value is less than input value
elif root.value < value:
  root.right_child = self.__recursive_remove(value, root.right_child)

# delete node if root.value == value
elif root.value == value:
  if root.left_child is None and root.right_child is None:
    return None
  elif root.left_child is None:
    return root.right_child
  elif root.right_child is None:
    return root.left_child
  
  node = min_val_node(root.right_child)
  root.value = node.value
  root.right_child = self.__recursive_remove(root.value, root.right_child)
return root


def remove_element(self, value):
return self.__recursive_remove(value, self.__root)
```

My deletion method works fine for most cases except when I'm trying to remove the root node and I could not figure out what the problem is. It seems like my recursive deletion method was unable to change the value of the root node but the code did change the root value to the smallest value from the right subtree. Apologies for my crap formatting, first time posting on StackOverflow :)

Comment: `remove_element()` needs to assign the returned value from `__recursive_remove()` back to `self.__root`.  As it is, you're throwing away any changes that apply directly to the root node; only changes deeper in the tree will work.

Comment: Thank you! Just the help i needed!